# Python Binary Search

Tags: python, loops, binary-search

I'm a beginner programmer and I wanted to make my own binary search algorithm from scratch without any help. It's safe to say it's not going well. I was hoping someone could find the error in my code. I fixed a few issues, but now I've ran into the issue where if can't find values greater than the middle index, and it is not ending once it reaches a single value not equal to the target.

```
    import random

userInput = 100
numbers = []

for i in range(100):
    numbers.append(random.randint(0, 100))

#Adding 100 to use as a test
numbers.append(100)
numbers.sort()
print(numbers)

def binarySearch(list, target):
    midIndex = int(len(list)/2)
    midValue = list[midIndex]

    if midValue == target:
        print("We found " + str(target))

    elif target > midValue:
        newList = numbers[midIndex:]
        binarySearch(newList, target)

    elif target < midValue:
        newList = numbers[:midIndex]
        binarySearch(newList, target)

    elif len(list) == 1 and list[0] != target:
        print(target + " is not in the list")

    else:
        print("It's not in the list")

binarySearch(numbers, userInput)
```

Comment: What is the error, what isn't working? As an aside, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded" that's the error that keeps appearing the most

Comment: the next answer will probably solve everything. try logging to understand what your code is doing at the crucial moments, if you have an debugger at hand even better, so you can understand what is happening step by step...
Also maybe try it with fewer numbers then 100 to have a better overview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main issues with your code:

1. `mid` is being used to represent both an index and a value.
2. The end of `binarySearch()` is never reached.

## Issue #1: `mid`

When creating `newList` using a slice of `list`, you are using `mid` as an index:

```
elif target > mid:
    newList = numbers[mid:]
```

However, `mid` is not an index. It is the value in the middle of `list`:

```
mid = list[int(len(list)/2)]
```

Try using two variables:

```
midIndex = int(len(list)/2)
midValue = list[midIndex]
```

## Issue #2: `binarySearch()`

`binarySearch()` never reaches the final `elif` to see if `target` is not in the list.

The final `elif` is only reached after checking the following conditions:

```
if midValue == target:
    ...
elif target > midValue:
    ...
elif target < midValue:
    ...
```

Clearly, if `midValue` and `target` are two numbers, one of these comparisons must return `True`.

Because of the order of the checks performed, `binarySearch()` never ends up getting to this section:

```
elif len(list) == 1 and list[0] != target:
    ...
```

To fix this issue, try rearranging your `if` statements so that `binarySearch()` reaches this part of the code.

Comment: Thank you that helped, but now I'm running into the issue where  if can't find values greater than the middle index, and it is not ending once it reaches a single value not equal to the target.

Comment: @03Wolf I updated my answer to include an explanation of how to fix your second issue.